# How to execute HTML form before java code in servlet page? Or how to arrange the html tags and tags inside response printer?

Tags: html, jsp

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySdhS.png)I am having a JSP where I have called a navigation page to display the navigation at the top.
Now, when I want to print the values inside a list to the page it automatically prints at the top of the page and the navigation goes down.
Is there a way to control the execution of java code and HTML code in JSP page?

```
    <%@page import="com.DB.Config.TimeSheetData" import="java.util.List"
    import="com.DB.Config.Timesheet"%>
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<jsp:include page="HomePage.jsp" />
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<title>Weekly generated Tme Sheet</title>
</head>
<body>
    <style>
        .TimeSheetForm {
            margin-top: 100px;
        }
    </style>
    <%
        HttpSession sessions = request.getSession();
        String UserName = "", Password = "";
        TimeSheetData timeSheetData = new TimeSheetData();

        try {
            UserName = sessions.getAttribute("UserName").toString();
            Password = sessions.getAttribute("Password").toString();
            System.out.println("UserName : " + UserName + " and password is : " + Password);
            System.out.println(UserName + " user entered the TimeSheet Approval page");

        } catch (NullPointerException ne) {
            System.out.println("This is coz User Details are null at time sheet page");
        }
        List<Timesheet> TIMESHEET = timeSheetData.getTimeSheet(UserName);

        for (Timesheet TS : TIMESHEET) {
            System.out.println(TS.getUserName() + " " + TS.getAttendence() + "  " + TS.getWorkingime() + "  "
                    + TS.getActualWorkingTime() + " " + TS.getBreakTime() + "   " + TS.getDate());
        }
    %>
    <form class="TimeSheetForm">
        <h4>Time Sheet</h4>
        <table align="center">

            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr></tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h5 style="text-align: center; color: white;">WEEK OF
                        THE YEAR</h5></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; color: white;">MONDAY</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; color: white;">TUESDAY</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; color: white;">WEDNESDAY</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; color: white;">THURSDAY</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; color: white;">FRIDAY</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; color: white;">SATURSDAY</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td style="text-align: center; color: white;">SUNDAY</td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><h5 style="text-align: center; color: white;">Value</h5></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Moday"
                    style="width: 120px; height: 20px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Tuesday"
                    style="width: 120px; height: 20px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Wednesday"
                    style="width: 120px; height: 20px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Thursday"
                    style="width: 120px; height: 20px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Friday"
                    style="width: 120px; height: 20px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Saturday"
                    style="width: 120px; height: 20px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
                <td><input type="text" name="Sunday"
                    style="width: 120px; height: 20px; text-align: center; border-radius: 10px" /></td>
                <td></td>
                <td></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
        <br> <br>
        <table align="center">
            <tr>
                <td><input type="button" name="Submit" value="Submit"
                    class="buttons"></td>
                <td><input type="button" name="Copy" value="Copy"
                    class="buttons"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <%int count = 0;
    response.getWriter().print("<div>");
    for (Timesheet TS : TIMESHEET) {
        if (count == 0) {
            response.getWriter().print(
                    "<select style=\"width: 300px; text-align: center;position:fixed;top:400px;left:533px;\">");
        }

        response.getWriter().print("<option value=" + TS.getDate() + ">" + TS.getDate() + "</option>");
        count++;
        if (count == TIMESHEET.size()) {
            response.getWriter().print("</select>");
        }

    }
    response.getWriter().print("</div>");
    %>
    <%
        response.getWriter().print("<form>");
        response.getWriter().print("<table align=\"center\" width=\"80%\">");
        response.getWriter().print("<tr>");
        response.getWriter().print("<td width=\"20%\"><h5>Date</h5></td>");
        response.getWriter().print("<td width=\"20%\"><h5>Working Time</h5></td>");
        response.getWriter().print("<td width=\"20%\"><h5>Actual Working Time</h5></td>");
        response.getWriter().print("<td width=\"20%\"><h5>Break</h5></td>");
        response.getWriter().print("<td width=\"20%\"><h5>Attendence</h5></td>");
        response.getWriter().print("</tr>");
        response.getWriter().print("<tr>");
        response.getWriter().print("<td width=\"20%\"></td>");
        response.getWriter().print("</tr></table></form>");
    %>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit your question and show your code.

Comment: yes sounds like you want javascript. Post your code.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, please review my code.

Comment: The code in for loop is getting printed even before the call of HomeaPage called in the 6th line of the code.